# Salesforce Einstein - Create and Train the Dataset - Trailhead Challenge

Tags: apex, administration, trailhead, einstein

Trailhead consists of creating a Dataset with the given URL(https://developer.salesforce.com/files/Cats.zip)

But how can we create our own Dataset, if we have all the images in Local system.

Comment: Please, can you provide the URL of the trailhead module this relate to?

Comment: Here is the Link to that Trailhead:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-a-cat-rescue-app-that-recognizes-cat-breeds/cat-recognition-app-create-train-dataset

Comment: Does the below answer help you, or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailhead module used a service class called [EinsteinVision_PredictionService](https://github.com/muenzpraeger/salesforce-einstein-platform-apex/blob/master/force-app/main/default/classes/Einstein_PredictionService.cls) to get the data from the zip and then load it into the Einstein REST API..

```
public Einstein_Dataset createDatasetFromUrlAsync(String url) {
    System.debug('Starting createDatasetFromUrlAsync call from URL ' + url + ' for type ' + typeString + '.');
    Einstein_HttpBodyPartDatasetUrl parts = new Einstein_HttpBodyPartDatasetUrl(url, typeString);
    Einstein_HttpClient client = new Einstein_HttpClient(this, '/datasets/upload', parts.build());
    client.isPost(true);
    System.debug('Target URL is ' + client.getUrl());
    client.execute();
    while(isExecuting()) {
        System.debug('Status is: ' + isExecuting());
    }
    System.debug('Call createDatasetFromUrlAsync has been executed.');
    if (!client.isError()) {
        Einstein_Dataset dataset = (Einstein_Dataset)client.getParser().readValueAs(Einstein_Dataset.class);
        System.debug('New dataset with id ' + dataset.id + ' has been created.');
        return dataset;
    }
    handleError(client.getStatusCode(), client.getResponseError());
    return null;
}
```

All the source code is here:

- [salesforce-einstein-platform-apex](https://github.com/muenzpraeger/salesforce-einstein-platform-apex)

You can follow the Apex code example to understand how they have done it.

The Einstein REST API documentation will also help:

- [Introduction to Salesforce Einstein Vision](https://metamind.readme.io/v2/docs)
- [Create a Dataset From a Zip File Synchronously](https://metamind.readme.io/docs/create-a-dataset-zip-async)